# how to handle ValueError:Julian Day must be positive

Tags: python-3.x

I read netcdf file i got error 'ValueError: Julian Day must be positive' .please suggest:

```
dtime,beta_row,ht_data=[],[],[]
f =Dataset(path) 
dtime.extend(netCDF4.num2date(f.variables['time'][:],f.variables['time'].units))
```

Comment: use a positive value. thats about as much help as anyone can give you since you dont show whats in your data or the stack trace of the error

Comment: look my data contain some negative values: masked_array(data = [3654115201.0 3654115216.0 3654115231.0 ..., -1.2861391081954512e+47
 -2.153483274096952e+47 -1.112594568902308e+45],
             mask = [False False False ..., False False False],
       fill_value = 9.96920996839e+36)

Comment: what does `f.variables['time']` contain

Comment: f.variables['time'][:] conatin masked_array(data = [3654115201.0 3654115216.0 3654115231.0 ..., -1.2861391081954512e+47
 -2.153483274096952e+47 -1.112594568902308e+45],
             mask = [False False False ..., False False False],
       fill_value = 9.96920996839e+36)

dtime=np.array(dtime)

Comment: so can you update the question with a minimal reproducable exampe that we can run to reproduce the error

Comment: I can reproduce the error with: `num2date(-2.153483274096952e+47,'days since 2010-01-01 00:00:00')`, which brings me to the question: do you even need the date value for these filling values? Do not use such values when converting to dates - either replace before calling `num2date` with "normal" values and delete as missing dates or some other way. Even positive values 2.153483274096952e+47 are just too large!

Comment: great...now u understand my question......I cannt skip those negative values,.....pls tell me how to remove negative sign from array values.keep all positive sign values are remains.only change negative sign values to positive sign.